# Hide a range on x-axis flot graphs and show it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, linechart

I am using flot chart for displaying data dynamically. See my [implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/CSJsLb6VZOlsTgbeDI6e?p=preview).
I need to hide graph starting from 200 to 250 (x-axis) and then after every 30 milliseconds, show a part of it. e.g after first 30 milliseconds x-axis will be updated to 260, after 60 milliseconds 270 and so on.

```
// Chart Options
    var dynamicChartOptions = {
        series: {
            label: "Server Process Data",
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 0.2,
                fill: 1,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.03)', '#000']
                }
            },
            color: '#000',
            shadowSize: 1
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            font: {
                lineHeight: 13,
                style: 'normal',
                color: '#000',
                size: 11
            },
            shadowSize: 0

        },
        xaxis: {
            tickColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            show: true,
            font: {
                lineHeight: 13,
                style: 'normal',
                color: '#000',
                size: 11
            },
            shadowSize: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 250
        },
        grid: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            labelMargin:10,
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            mouseActiveRadius:6,
            markings: [
                {xaxis: {from:  200, to: 250}, yaxis: {from: -3, to: 100}, color: "#0000bb"},
                //{xaxis: {from: 10, to: 12}, yaxis: {from: -3, to: 100}, color: "#0000bb"},
                //{xaxis: {from: 20, to: 20},                            color: "#0000bb"},
                //{yaxis: {from: 20, to: 20},                            color: "#0000bb"}
            ],
        },
        legend:{
            container: '.flot-chart-legends--dynamic',
            backgroundOpacity: 0.5,
            noColumns: 0,
            lineWidth: 1,
            labelBoxBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
        }
    };
```